# Is it possible to add lore to a floppy disk?

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm working on a project that uses floppy disks like cards, and I wanted to know if there was any way I could display information on the "card" using the minecraft lore system.

Currently I have no clue if this is possible or not.

Comment: what do you mean by "minecraft lore system"? are you referring to minecraft gameplay mechanics or a mod/plugin?

Comment: @chesiren AFIACT, *lore* refers to a field in the JSON metadata of Minecraft items that enables a type of [flavour text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor_text). That's as much as I know from a quick set of searches.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. Oka would be correct, sorry I did not specify what I meant by that.